# Elastic Beanstack - Rails - git deploy and deploy hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, hook, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to setup Elastic Beanstalk for my existing rails application.

I was successful in doing the sample foo app.

These are the questions I have

1. I need the deployment to happen from my git repository and not from my local path where I am deploying. How do I do that for the sample foo app.
2. I need to have a before_symlink deploy hook. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have addressed these issues.

1. git aws.push takes all the commited things to git and then deploys it. Local changes are not impacted.
2. Created a config file under .ebextensions

More here - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html